# Finding K largest elements in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find the K largest elements in BST but my code flow is not happenging properly. e.g Consider the BST as below

```
             9
           /   \
          7     12
         /  \  /   \
        6  10  11  16
```

My code flow is happening in the order 16 --> 12 --> 9, though I am trying to have it 16 --> 12 --> 11.

Code as below

```
public class FindKLargestElements {


private static int n =0;

public static int[] findLarge(Node node, int large[], int k) {

    if (node == null) return large;

    if (k == 0) return large;

    findLarge(node.getRightNode(), large, k);

    if (k >0) {
        large[n] = node.getValue();
        k = k -1;
        n = n +1;
        return large;

    }

    findLarge(node.getLeftNode(), large, k);

    return large;

}

}
```

I have fixed this now. Here is the final code.

This is what I did

1. Removed the return statement from if k > 0 block
2. Changed the primitive k to class level rather than recursive method level as updated to it were getting lost.

   ```
   public class FindKLargestElements {


   private static int n =0;
   private static int k =3;

   public static int[] findLarge(Node node, int large[]) {

       if (node == null) return large;

       if (k == 0) return large;

       findLarge(node.getRightNode(), large);

       if (k >0) {
           large[n] = node.getValue();
           k = k -1;
           n = n +1;

       }

       findLarge(node.getLeftNode(), large);

       return large;

   }
   ```

   }

Comment: The depicted tree is invalid, the "10" could never be on the left.

Answer (score 3):

Please try below program

```
public class FindKLargestElements {

private static int n =0;
private static int large[];

public static void findLarge(Node node, int k) {

    if (node == null) return;
    if (k == 0) return;

    findLarge(node.getRightNode(), k);

    if (k >0) {
        large[n] = node.getValue();
        k = k-1;
        n = n+1;

    }

    findLarge(node.getLeftNode(), k);

}

}
```

Comment: It doesnt make any difference

Comment: Basically I have commented the return statement from the if(k>0) block in your program so that left node traversal will happen before return. so it should work

 if (k >0) {
        large[n] = node.getValue();
        k = k-n-1;
        n = n +1;
        // return large;
    }

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a very different but way more simpler and effective way of getting k largest element of a binary search tree.

**1. Use inorder traversal to get the sorted elements in a list or array**

```
function inorder(node)   {
      if (node == null)
         return;
      inorder(node.left);
      visit(node);
      inorder(node.right);
}
```

**2. Access the last K elements by starting from the last element.**

```
use for loop or while
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way will be to create the mirror of the given BST and do an inorder traversal of first K elements. Those will be the k largest elements. The drawback of this approach is that you are wasting time to create the mirror tree but the advantage you get later is that you don't have to traverse the entire n elements later.

Since k could be as large as n, in the worst case, we still have to traverse each element in the BST. So simply doing an inorder traversal of the original BST and returning last k elements in the inorder traversal should be an easier option.